# Web Scraping redirect

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping

I am able to scrape most sites with the following code but some redirect me to => distil_r_blocked.html

This is the header I get

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK Date: Mon, 26 Jun 2017 20:30:12 GMT Content-Type: text/html Transfer-Encoding: chunked Connection: keep-alive Vary: Accept-Encoding Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT Cache-Control: no-cache Cache-Control: private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate Edge-Control: no-store, bypass-cache Surrogate-Control: no-store, bypass-cache
```

and this is my code

```
function file_get_contents_curl($target_url,$json=false){
$ch = curl_init();
$headers = array();
if($json) {
    $headers[] = 'Content-type: application/json';
    $headers[] = 'X-HTTP-Method-Override: GET';
}
$options = array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $target_url,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array($headers),
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 300,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => 1,
    CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER => 1,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_HEADER => 1,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => 1,
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 3,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 10,
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.9) Gecko/20071025 Firefox/2.0.0.9');
curl_setopt_array($ch,$options);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
if($response === false || curl_error($ch)) {
    curl_close($ch);
    return false;
} else {
    curl_close($ch);
    return $response;
}
}

// Create a curl handle to a non-existing location
$ch = curl_init($target_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

if(curl_exec($ch) === false)
{
echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}
else
{
echo 'Operation completed without any errors';
}

$data = file_get_contents_curl($target_url);
$html = str_get_html($data);
```

Is there anyway around the redirect?

Thanks, Simon

Comment: perhaps have the decency to respect them and not scrape those who dont want you to ?

Answer (score 1):

Your cURL option `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` is set to TRUE, which means it will follow redirects. Set it to 0 and it will not follow the redirect. You're also using this option twice when it doesn't need to.

In regards to retrieving the original content, you won't be able to control this as the server is controlling the response. At best, you can try to spoof headers or use different IP's, but this is generally frowned upon... mostly because it's sketchy behavior (in my opinion).